# how to manage properly datable.js with jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

how could I manage properly the datatables with jquery.ajax syntax and codeigniter also? I want to use my own syntax like:

```
$.ajax({
  url:  url, 
})
```

I woould like to someone could help me or give me part of code to annalise that.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "scripts/post.php",
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "first_name" },
                    { "data": "last_name" },
                    { "data": "position" },
                    { "data": "office" },
                    { "data": "start_date" },
                    { "data": "salary" }
                ]
            } );
        } );
```

Comment: You can use whatever value you want in the url parameter.  It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i meant that i dont want to use the ajax from datatable, but $.ajax() it's better on my own but how can I integrate it?

Answer (score 1):

To perform your AJAX query separately from your DataTables init:

Do your AJAX call and store the results in an object, and then pass the object to a function that initiates your table:

```
var obj = {};
$.ajax({
    // your ajax parameters
}).success(function (data) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
    //..perhaps verify obj has results before passing to dataToTable function
     dataToTable(obj);
});
```

dataToTable function looks something like:

```
function dataToTable(dataSet) {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "data": dataSet,
        //..your other datatables settings
    });

}
```

Comment: cant be both in the same fuction?

Comment: @azdejo Yes, they can. The point is that you can pass the JSON data to the `"data"` option in the DataTable initialization as a Javascript object. It doesn't matter how you set that object to hold the results of the ajax call.

Comment: then can i change the "ajax" from datatable for $.ajax({})

Comment: @azdejo I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you're saying you want to replace `"ajax"` with `$.ajax({})`, then no, you can't. `"ajax"` is an option defined by DataTables, which has to be structured the way you have it in your first example. You can use `"data"` to get the data from another source, which in this case is your own ajax request. (BTW, if you use the @Name in your comment it will alert the named person that you've responded, otherwise they won't know automatically).

Comment: is it other datable for codeigniter using $.ajax({})

Comment: @azdejo - Codeigniter has nothing to do with datatables or ajax.  Codeigniter is a PHP framework, and PHP is a server side language.  DataTables is jQuery plugin, and jQuery/JavaScript is a client side language.  You can POST or GET data to a PHP page using AJAX, but the structure of your jQuery as it relates to passing data to DataTables has nothing to do with PHP or codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "scripts/post.php",   // codeigniter method url("scripts/get_data")
    "aoColumns": [ { "bSortable": true }, { "bSortable": false }, { "bSortable": true }, { "bSortable": false }],      
});
```

where sAjaxSource is just like the url parameter of ajax.